# Absolute first time using scheme, Simple list manipulation

Tags: list, scheme, addition

I am flying blind on scheme, and I feel like once I answer this question the rest of my homework should progress smoothly.

I'm defining a function that takes a list as its sole argument, then returns the same list with the first element added to the rest. For instance:

```
(addFirst ‘(4 3 2 1))   =>   (8 7 6 5)
```

I have a feeling that I should be using the map and car functions here... but I just can't seem to get it exactly right. My current version of this code looks like:

```
(define (addlist x) ;adds the first element of a list to all other elements
  (define a (car x)) ;a is definitely the first part of the list
  (map (+ a) x)
)
```

How can I make the addition function work this way? Obviously I can't provide a list as a parameter, but should I be using car again or recursion?

Okay, for posterity, here's the completed, correct, formatted code:

```
(define (addlist x) ;adds the first element of a list to all other elements
  (define a (car x)) ;a is definitely the first part of the list
  (map (lambda (y) (+ a y)) x)
)
```

Comment: Interestingly, in your initial attempt, you seem to be thinking like a Haskell programmer, where the expression `(+) a` really does evaluate to a function which adds `a` to its argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Map takes a function and n lists. So you need to transform (+ a) into a function that takes one argument (as you want to map over one list).

```
(map (lambda (item) ... do something to add a to item ...) x)
```

Comment: You're exactly right, I just figured it out. I'll post the completed code as an answer, thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Happy Scheme-ing! (or would it be Scheming?)

Comment: So I can't answer my own question for 8 more hours.

Comment: Okay, so this was as simple as it seemed. I guess I was hung up on the definition of procedure and function here. Here's the completed code that does exactly what I need it to do:

    (define (addlist x) ;adds the first element of a list to all other elements
      (define a (car x)) ;a is definitely the first part of the list
      (map (lambda (y) (+ a y)) x)
    )

Thanks again to @Ross Larson

Comment: Looks like you're new to Stack Overflow: give @RossLarson a bump and click the "check" next to his answer.

Comment: Done and Done! Forgot to do it before rushing out of my lab this morning